# How can I get the Authorization in the Headers while I use the 'credentials include' option?

Tags: fetch, credentials, setcookie

I was able to access the 'Authorization' header before I added the 'credentials' option, but I had to add the 'credentials' option in order to set cookies.

However, now I can't retrieve the 'Authorization' header. Does using the 'credentials' option impact accessing the headers? And how can I set cookies and retrieve the token from the headers?

Here is my code.

```
      const response = await fetch(`${DOMAIN}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true" },
        body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
        credentials: "include",
      });

      const token = response.headers.get("X-Amzn-Remapped-Authorization") || null;
      dispatch(setToken(token));

      const data = await response.json();
```